# Access to Liferay

Tags: amazon-web-services, liferay

I have installed Liferay on the AWS server and integrated with Amazon S3. I am able to access Liferay on the server by giving localhost:8080 but I am not able to access it from my laptop by giving Hostname:8080(Public IP is not static). Can anyone tell me why I am not able to access Liferay from my laptop. Is there any other steps to follow?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. This site is designed to provide answers to specific programming problems. I doubt that your question fits in our format. Kindly check the FAQ on which kind of question can be asked here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your server with hostname, you have to front your Liferay app server with http server (apache web server).

Add following into portal-ext.properties file

```
web.server.http.port=80
```

Go to LR control panel -> site -> Site-setting -> Site URL -> Virtual Host. Set your virtual host here. e.g. **www.abc.com**

install apache web server, if you haven't.

Add following into apache's **000-default.conf** file

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

restart apache.

pass host entry on your local system.

there you go.... it's done, you don't event need to access with port **8080** either.

Hope it'll help.